# python 3 round on one numpy float unexpectedly yielding float

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, types

I have an np.array `startIdx` originating from a list of tuples consisting of integer and float fields:

```
>>> startIdx, someInt, someFloat = np.array(resultList).T
>>> startIdx
array([0.0, 111.0, 333.0]) # 10 to a few 100 positive values of the order of 100 to 10000
>>> round(startIdx[2])
333.0 # oops
>>> help(round)
Round [...] returns an int when called with one argument, otherwise the same type as the number.
>>> round(np.pi)
3
>>> round(np.pi, 2) # the optional argument is the number of decimal digits
3.14
round([0.0, 111.0, 333.0][2]) # to test whether it's specific for numpy arrays.
333
```

The float currently works (as index into numpy arrays) but yields a warning:

```
 VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future
```

I could avoid the conversion from tuples to arrays (and int to float) by collecting my results in a grossly oversized record array (with an int field `''startIdx''`).

I could use something like `int(. + 0.1)`, which is also ugly. Would `int(round(.))` or even `int(.)` safely yield correct results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [70]: startIdx=np.array([0.0, 111.0, 333.0])
In [71]: startIdx
Out[71]: array([   0.,  111.,  333.])
```

If you need an integer array, use `astype`:

```
In [72]: startIdx.astype(int)
Out[72]: array([  0, 111, 333])
```

not `round`:

```
In [73]: np.round(startIdx)
Out[73]: array([   0.,  111.,  333.])
```

`np.array(resultList)` produces a float dtype array because some values are float.  `arr=np.array(resultList, dtype='i,i,f')` should produce a structured array with integer and float fields, assuming `resultList` is indeed a list of tuples.

```
 startIdx = arr['f0']
```

should then be an integer dtype array.

I expect the memory use of the structured array to be the same as for the float one.

Comment: Thank you for both answers. I spent a few Watt-hours to check that `astype(int)` works correctly on `'f4'` in the range of positive `int32`, which lets me suspect that the elements of my test array of `dtype='f4'` were never represented as 32-bit float.

Comment: Do you think `round(startIdx[2])` yielding a float result is a bug? Note that I used Python's round(), not np.round(), which I know yields float results.

Comment: I dived into the documentation (beyond the output of help()) and found the reason: "For a general Python object ``number``, ``round(number, ndigits)`` delegates to ``number.__round__(ndigits)``." Thus, my call ends up calling numpy's round(), which yields float results. Test: `round(float(startIdx[2]))` yields the intended int-type result.